# Flashing an official Samsung galaxy tab kernel

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-10, kernel, 3.2-honeycomb

I have a Galaxy Tab 10.1 (GT-P7510) with Android 3.2 and kernel 2.6.36.3 installed. I'm building a customized kernel using Samsung's official kernel source code for research purposes. I do not need to install any third party hacks or do fancy things. I just need to flash my own kernel to test it on the device.

I have been searching around the web for a clean way of flashing a modified Samsung kernel build on this device, but I'm not able to make sense of the results I'm getting. I'm not sure if my device has an unlocked bootloader or not.

Would anyone clarify how things work with regard to flashing a new kernel? 
Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you will need to root your tablet. This is relatively easy, especially with the galaxy because it's so popular. Head on over to the XDA Forums (www.xda-developers.com) and navigate to the galaxy 10.1 section. This youtube video also will do it for you: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=krQDP7xYlWg

BE CAREFUL. Follow the steps exactly. You don't want to brick your device.

After that, you'll have ClockworkMod. So first things first: zip up your kernel, then copy it to your device. Most of the time, tablets require sd-cards in order to install things from recovery, so pop in an sd-card and copy the zipped folder here.

Then, reboot into recovery (turn device off, then hold up volume button and power at the same time). You'll want to wipe your cache partition and davlik cache first. Once this is done, go to install zip from sd-card, find your folder with the kernel, and that's it!

BEFORE YOU DO THIS, do a backup of your current system, just in case your kernel really messes up your device. Hope this helps!

Comment: This is great answer. I'm going to try this and see what happens. By the way, will I be able to use the kernel from Android's open source or I should stick to Samsung's kernel?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: what files from the kernel source need to be in the zip file?

Comment: I would stick to the Samsung kernel. That way you can be sure your firmware will still all work correctly (you don't want your wifi to suddenly not work anymore). I've never made my own kernel, so I can't tell you that, but it should be on the XDA forums. I'm guessing you include all the files needed for building the kernel.

Comment: I'm replacing zImage in a working kernel image with my custom zImage from my kernel build and it looks like working.

Comment: good, glad its working out for you, let me know what the final outcome is

Comment: I'm trying to test if my custom kernel is really the one that is running. I used kernel manager pro to flash it and it flashed it with no errors.. but I'm still suspicious about it. Do you know if there is a clear way to test it?

Comment: It should tell you what kernel you're running in settings->about phone->kernel

Comment: Update: My kernel is not installed. Actually the issue is more complicated than I thought. I had to install it through recovery. Once I install it, the screen goes scrambled! No one is answering me on xda-developers either :P

Comment: Woah. I'm not real sure what that means... I would maybe post this as another question, I'm not going to be able to help you out much with this one. The only thing I can thing of is your kernel isn't decoding the picture that's on the screen correctly. Are you using the samsung or the android kernel?

Comment: I'm using a stock Samsung kernel.

Comment: What did you do to the kernel to change it?

Comment: Very minor changes. Putting a few printk to see if my kernel is up. I have not really change it yet. I'm starting a new question on this.